# Advantages of using Lightning Connect as opposed to APIs?

Tags: api, lightning-connect

As far as I can tell, the price for Lightning Connect is just shy of $50,000 per year. I'm just curious, in consideration of this cost, why would one be better served using Lightning Connect as opposed to the various APIs provided by Salesforce?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure on pricing, but what I can confirm is that Lightning Connect follows [OData Protocol](http://www.odata.org/blog/salesforce-external-object-integration-using-lightning-connect-with-odata/) and it is getting better with each release.

1. Big players like Microsoft, SAP are supporting this out of box.
2. Data is not saved in SFDC so you will save cost on space .
3. Data will be always realtime.
4. You dont need any developement effort to connect SFDC with external applications, Even business users or Admins can use point and click to integrate.
5. If you have ligtning connect license, you can connect to external system anytime without any code.

If we choose custom developement over ligtning connect, It may cost sometime more and any change will need developement, you may need consider cost of ETL tool as well if go with developement.

Comment: I couldn't anything supporting this in the documentation, but I imagine retrieving data from external sources is not held to API request usage limits.

Comment: There are some limits. The ones for OData are outlined here: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=odata_general_limits.htm&language=en_US